# Redirect to relative django path

Tags: python, django

See these examples:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar') #view name with optional arguments

def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('/some/url/')
```

There is no identification to tell Django if the first argument is a view or a URL. I wanted to specify 'login', a relative path, but it looks for the view. On my local host, I had it working with '/login' since I was working in the root directory, but now after I deployed my project to my web server, I put it in a folder. Is specifying '/myfolder/login' (absolute path) the only way to use the redirect shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

...

return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse('login', kwargs={'foo': 'bar'}) )
```